# Reference Persistance And Passing A Variable Number Of Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, static, polymorphism, variadic-functions

Below, I have written simple code that re-creates problems that have emerged as my application is growing.

**Problem Statement:**
I have a class that needs to be used to create polymorphic objects which each require a variable number of arrays as input.  So I might have two to five of these objects instantiated throughout the time my app is running.  And between them, these objects might have 15 arrays.  What's more, some of these arrays need to be modifyable from a variety of different, other objects after they are created, not just by the objects that created or "house" them.

**Three Questions:**
**1.)** What is the most stable/recommended way of passing a number of different arrays into a class?  I have used a varargs approach below, but am not sure if this is the best way.
**2.)** How can I avoid problems due to the static key word?  You will see that the code in Main.java below throws errors related to the static key word.  I hesitate to allow all instances of the class to share a single copy of the array.  All of this code is in an internal frame in the GUI, and I may later want to allow the user to create multiple internal frames, each with their own instances of all this code for completely different data sets.
**3.)** How can I enable various other objects to edit and otherwise manipulate these arrays after the arrays have been created? You can see below that I am passing arrays to Another.java, which then assigns those arrays to local class variables before editing the array.  Is the local array the same object as was passed into Another.java, or have I made an error by creating duplicate arrays?

**Code Samples:**
The code samples below to illustrate what I need to do.

Can anyone show me a re-written version of the code below that fixes these problems?

Also, I would very much appreciate any links you can send to articles about how these problems are best addressed.

Main.java

```
public class Main {
int arrayLength = 10;
double[] array1 = new double[arrayLength];
double[] array2 = new double[arrayLength];
double[] array3 = new double[arrayLength];
double[] array4 = new double[arrayLength];
double[] array5 = new double[arrayLength];

static void makeHandleArrays(){// how do I avoid static errors thrown here?
    HandleArrays firstHandleArrays = new HandleArrays();
    firstHandleArrays.arrayLength(array1);

    HandleArrays secondHandleArrays = new HandleArrays();
    secondHandleArrays.arrayLength(array1,array2,array3); //varargs approach
}

public static void main(String[] args){//how do I avoid static errors thrown here?
    makeHandleArrays();
    Another myOtherClass = new Another(array1,array2);
}}
```

HandleArrays.java

```
public class HandleArrays {//Is this varargs approach the best way to handle a variable number of arrays as inputs?
double[][] dataArrays;
int numArrays;
void arrayLength(double[] ...ds){
    dataArrays = new double[ds.length][];
    numArrays = ds.length;
    for(int i = 0;i<ds.length;i++){
        dataArrays[i]=ds[i];
    }
}
}
```

EditArrays.java

```
public class EditArrays {
      double[] thisHereArray=new double[10];
EditArrays(double[] arrayToEdit){  
                thisHereArray=arrayToEdit;
    thisHereArray[6]=4.678;//does this edit the same object that was passed into the class?  Or did I make an error with the name change?  
}
}
```

Another.java

```
public class Another {
double[] localArray1;
double[] localArray2;

Another(double[] anArray){
    localArray1=anArray;
    EditArrays myEditArrays = new EditArrays(localArray1);// does the name change mean that this line is NOT editing the same anArray?
}
Another(double[] anArray, double[] anotherArray){
    localArray1=anArray;
    localArray2=anotherArray;
    EditArrays myEditArrays = new EditArrays(localArray1);// does the name change mean that this line is NOT editing the same anArray?
    EditArrays anotherEditArrays = new EditArrays(localArray2);// does the name change mean that this line is NOT editing the same anotherArray?
}
}
```

Comment: At the moment, all `HandleArrays` is doing is providing a _shallow copy_ of the array.  All of the code in the constructor could be replaced with `dataArrays = ds;`.  `numArrays` is worthless - `dataArrays.length` should be used instead.  None of this code is thread-safe.  What are you attempting to do?

Comment: @X-Zero, What I am attempting to do is to reduce a large amount of code into a smaller amount of code, so that it becomes easier to edit, debug, build-upon, etc.  What you have already done has given me a lot of direction in that effort.  I think that I need to get further along in my refactoring process before posting my code, and then probably in separate postings.  At the moment, what would really help would be if you were willing to explicitly re-write Main.java so that it no longer throws static errors.  If you can help me by providing an actual example to work with, it would really help.

Comment: an actual working example of Main.java(without the static errors), that is.  Thank you again very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a number of different concerns happening here, so I'll try to address them.

- 1) 'Varags' approach

You're not actually using `varags` - you're using `overloading`.  Rather than having multiple methods with increasing numbers of variables, you can simple declare:

```
void methodName(dataType...variableName) {
    // method code here
}
```

Which will give you an array of the input data type (so, you'll end up with an array of arrays, in this case).  Oftentimes, the varags will be referenced in a `foreach` loop.  The only condition on their use is that they have to be declared as the last parameter; it will also be important to remember that actually providing them is completely optional.

- 2) `static` keyword issues

The issue you're facing with the `static` keyword is that you're attempting to access *instance* variables inside a *static* (class-level) method.  `static` methods can only access `static` variables and variables they were provided as part of the input parameters.  In order to get around the 'static errors', you're going to have to pass either the instance of the class in (via a `this` reference), or a specific array, or modify the array reference to be static:

Static references:

```
public class Main {
    static double[] arr = new double[10];

    public static void main(String...args) {
        arr[0] = 5;
    }
}
```

Passing in instance reference:

```
public class Main {
    double[] arr = new double[10];

    static void modifyArray(double[] modArr) {
        modArr[0] = 3;
    }

    public static void main(String...args) {
        Main inst = new Main();
        modifyArray(inst.arr);
    }
}
```

- 3) Editing the arrays externally

You seem to have some confusion over how java handles input parameters.
Java handles all input parameters as pass-by-value, sometimes known as pass-a-copy.  This is covered in detail elsewhere on this site, so I'm not going to go through all of it here.
What it means for your code, though, is this:

```
EditArrays(double[] arrayToEdit) {
    thisHereArray = arrayToEdit;
    thisHereArray[6] = 4.678;
}
```

actually modifies *one* array - to which there are *three* (or more) references.  That is, `thisHereArray`, and `arrayToEdit`, as well as whatever reference (say, `localArray1` from `Another`) was passed in, all point to the *exact same array* in memory.  This code produces an equivalent effect:

```
EditArrays(double[] arrayToEdit) {
    thisHereArray = arrayToEdit;
    arrayToEdit[6] = 4.678;
}
```

All you've done is duplicated the references, *not* the actual array.  Depending on your requirements, this could be good or bad.  In a multithreaded environment, this will cause a *huge* number of (nearly untraceable/reproducable) errors.  In a single-threaded environment, you're probably fine.

- Providing more feedback

Without knowing your exact requirements, it's a little hard to give additional feedback.  I can give some general recommendations, though:

1. Only use arrays for definite or permentantly size-bound collections.  Otherwise, use members of the `Collections` framework.
2. Don't create and name variables in the format `variableSameTypeSameName1`, `variableSameTypeSameName2`.  You either have a collection of the same things (like you appear to have here) and they should all be put into a collection (array), or they all represent *different* things and should be named as such (`peopleToInvite`, `peopleToExclude`, `peopleToKill`).
3. Do ***NOT*** perform edits of external (passed as parameter) objects inside of a constructor.  You can pass a reference to the object to be edited, and call a method afterwards to edit it.
4. Don't use `System.out.println()` inside of 'regular' or production methods (unless you're making a console application, which I doubt).  It's fine for debugging/miscellaneuos testing when you're checking things.
5. You mention this code is running in `an internal frame in the GUI`, although you don't provide any Swing/AWT code.  *Never* mix any UI code with 'backend' or model code directly (it's hard to tell what you're attempting, so this may not be an issue) - the headaches it causes should be avoided.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to write such a thoughful answer.  Thank you.  For question#3, what syntax do you recommend for editing thisHereArray/arrayToEdit?  The array needs to be used elsewhere in the class, such as in the paintComponent, where it seems easier for it to be a class-level variable because it does not seem possible to pass method variables into the paintComponent.  I would like to write this in a way that is scalable for when I later may need to do multi-threaded programming.

Comment: yes, I caught that I was not using varargs correctly while I was reviewing my code before you replied.

Comment: note the code of HandleArrays is now changed, so that I am now putting the array of arrays into dataArrays[][].  I do not know how to decompose dataArrays[][] into a number of uniquely named arrays, so I imagine I need to refer to each array as dataArrays[0], dataArrays[1], etc. or to cycle through dataArrays[][] in a for loop.  Is this correct?

Comment: Sure you can pass 'local' or 'method' parameters, as well as instance parameters, into `paintComponent()`.  Do _not_ use `static` variables in multi-threaded programming (anything using Swing should be by default).  You're going to need to create what's known as a 'deepCopy' of any arrays used.  We'll be best able to help you if you tell us what you're attempting to accomplish - alternate methods may be better.  Post your entire source file if necessary (probably in a different question).

Comment: Thank you.  I will use this in my refactoring.  By the time I am ready to ask additional questions, the code will probably have changed enough that I will just put it in a new post then.